# Codeigniter multi image upload with folder create

Tags: codeigniter, image-upload

first please be gentle im a really big begginer.

Ok im making a real estate site and i really have no clue, i tried several things but i cant make it work.

My problem is when i add a new real estate to the site, the system generates an unique 7 characters long numeric string and inserts it in to the database.

So when i upload an image i would like that the system creates a folder named with this unique 7 characters long numeric string and place the images there.

here is my controller

```
<?php

class ihirdet extends CI_Controller
    {
        function index()
            {
                $this->load->view("header");

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('cim', 'Cím', 'min_length[10]|max_length[100]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('htipus', 'Hirdetés típusa', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('itipus', 'Ingatlan típusa', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('iallapot', 'Ingatlan állapota', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('jaras', 'Járás', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('telepules', 'Telepules', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('utca', 'Utca', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('hazszam', 'Házszám', 'required|numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('emelet', 'Emelet', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('telekterulet', 'Telekterület', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('alapterulet', 'Alapterület', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('ingatlanar', 'Ingatlan ára', 'required|numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('penznem', 'Pénznem', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('epitesev', 'Építés éve', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('szoba', 'Szoba', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('felszoba', 'Félszoba', 'numeric');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('futes', 'Fűtés', 'required');
                //$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Kép', 'callback_kep_ellenor');
                $this->load->model('hirdetes_model');

                if($this->form_validation->run() !== FAlSE)
                {
                    $this->hirdetes_model->kuld();


                //  redirect(base_url() . 'elado/adatlap/' . $this->input->post('azonosito'));
                } else {
                    $this->load->model('hirdetes_model');
                    $data['felh_inf'] = $this->hirdetes_model->felh_info();
                    $this->load->view("ihirdet_sablon", $data);
                }
                    $this->load->view("footer");
            }

        }

?>
```

I was testing, and i was able to upload only one image and create the folder.

My question is, how can i implant a multi imageupload in to my index function, with createing the folder.

And a validation so only create the folder and upload the images in it when the image input has a value, but if the user didnt fill out the form correctly, but the image is fine still dont create the folder and dont upload the image.

Please dont misunderstand me, i dont want anybody to write the codes for me, i just want a more expreienced developer to share his thougts how would he make it, no codes just share the idea, and i will try to make it by my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function tester($yourUniqueId){

 $this->load->library('upload'); 

 for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES); $i++)
 {

   $_FILES['userfile']['name']    = $_FILES['filename']['name'][$i];
   $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $_FILES['filename']['type'][$i];
   $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i];
   $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $_FILES['filename']['error'][$i];
   $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $_FILES['filename']['size'][$i];

   $config['file_name']     = $yourUniqueId.'/test_'.$i;
   $config['upload_path']   = './public/uploads/';
   $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
   $config['max_size']      = '0';
   $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

  $this->upload->initialize($config);

  if($this->upload->do_upload())
  {
    $error += 0;
  }else{
    $error += 1;
  }
 }

 if($error > 0){ return FALSE; }else{ return TRUE; }

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: could you please help? i run it just for a test, i named my inputs filename, but no matter what i do i always keep geting this error Message: Undefined index: filename

Comment: `$_FILES['filename']` might be named wrong. Make sure you have the right name on your input: `<input type="file" name="filename" />`

Comment: sorry for asking to much but like this?
<input type="file" name="filename1" />
<input type="file" name="filename2" />
<input type="file" name="filename3" />

because im getting the error this way too

Comment: make your input type like <input type="file" name="filename[]" /> for all the input file types and it should work

Comment: first sorry for asking so much stupid questions, and second rellyy big thanks for spearing time on my question and helping me. thank you